# Find the natural number $n>2$ such that $\frac{n!}{(n-1)!} + \frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!} = 2\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I'm unsure how I'm supposed to solve the equation:

$$\frac{n!}{(n-1)!} + \frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!} = 2\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!} $$ given that $n>2.$

Comment: Generally, asking people to do an entire problem for you, without showing any effort on your own, is frowned upon here.

Comment: I'm aware of that thank you, I had done the working up to that point but was unsure on how to continue

Comment: @Anna You should include that in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n! = n(n-1)!$

So, start simplifying the first part of your equality.

$\frac{n!}{(n-1)!} = \frac{n(n-1)!}{(n-1)!} = n$.

Do you see how to continue?

Comment: I'm at n^3 -3n^2 + 3n =6n^2 but I think I might have gone wrong?

Comment: @Anna Yes, you made some mistake on calculations.